# How can I check if an S3 key is empty using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

S3 doesn't support folders natively but they can be emulated with empty keys. So I can make a new folder by creating a key and not setting a value:

```
bucket.new_key('directory')
```

I want to determine if such a key is a directory or a file. I think this can be done by checking if the contents of the key are empty but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> S3 doesn't support folders natively but they can be emulated with empty keys.

That's only correct to a *very limited extent.*

The fact that the key refers to a 0-byte (empty) object is only a side effect. The important factor is that the key name ends in `/`.

> An object named with a trailing "/" displays as a folder in the Amazon S3 console.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html

So, your test is simple: if the key ends in `/`, that's a pretend folder placeholder.

Ordinary objects can be empty (simply an "empty file," such as the output from a logging operation that reported nothing), so emptiness would not be a valid test.

But what exactly does this do for you?

> they can be emulated

The above is only relevant in the S3 console.

- the only thing you accomplish by creating such an object is to give the console a picture of a folder to display, so that you can click on it to put files there, but
- if there are already objects with that same prefix, the console is already displaying a folder there anyway, and
- you can programmatically create the object `pics/funny/cat.jpg` without first creating `pics/` and `pics/funny/` and S3 will treat them no differently than if you had created folder placeholders, and
- deleting such an object doesn't delete the "contents" of the "folder" (so this isn't going to "emulate" a folder in that sense), and
- deleting such an object doesn't remove the folder icon from the console, unless there are no more objects in the bucket with that prefix.

You do not need these placeholder objects in order to work with the objects in a bucket as though they were hierarchical.

The List Objects request APIs allow you to specify a `prefix`, such as `myfolder/` to get a listing of all of the objects within `myfolder/` including all objects in sub-folders, or, if you specify the `delimiter` of `/`, you'll receive only the objects within that folder, not within subfolders.

These API operations do not need these special objects to be created.

S3 does not support *actual* folders, in the sense that nothing in S3 is stored "inside" or "under" something else.  This is for scalability.  S3 does, however, support *logical* folders, using the `delimiter`-handling logic built in to the APIs.

Comment: This is a nice overview of the logic on which S3 is built, but you do not help solve or approach the problem.

Comment: The problem is not with this answer, it is with the original question.  This answer solves the *actual problem*, and disregards the XY question of how to check if a key is empty.